# writing a C# Program that prompts the user for the said details and display them on the console

Tags: c#

writing a C# Program that prompts the user for the said details and displays them on the console.

Create the classes, along with the specified members as mentioned below.

question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code for the following question is not running. Can I please get some help. error is coming
error CS0122: `Game.game_name' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

My code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a game");
        string game_name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the maximum number of players");
        int max_players = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Game game = new Game();
        game.GameName = game_name;
        game.MaxNumPlayers = max_players;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a game that has time limit");
        game_name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the maximum number of players");
        max_players = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter time limit in minutes");
        int time_limit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        GameWithTimeLimit time_game = new GameWithTimeLimit();
        time_game.GameName = game_name;
        time_game.MaxNumPlayers = max_players;
        time_game.TimeLimit = time_limit;

        Console.WriteLine(game);
        Console.WriteLine(time_game);

    }

}
class Game
{
    string game_name;
    int max_players;
    public string GameName
    {
        set
        {
            this.game_name = value;
        }
    }
    public int MaxNumPlayers
    {
        set
        {
            this.max_players = value;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Maximum number of players for " + game_name + " is " + max_players;
    }
}
class GameWithTimeLimit : Game
{
    int time_limit;
    public int TimeLimit
    {
        set
        {
            this.time_limit = value;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.ToString());
        return "Time Limit for " + base.game_name + " is " + this.time_limit + " minutes";
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide more context around the error. Do you have a stacktrace? The error means you are trying to use `Game.game_name` outside of that class, but it is `private` not `public`. Fields, methods, etc default to `private` if not declared `public` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, when no access modifier is given to a class member it is defaulted to **private**. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels) for a description of access modifiers and their defaults.

A `private` member *cannot* be accessed from subclasses. This is why, in your `GameWithTimeLimit` class, your attempt to access `base.game_name` throws an error: `game_name` is a private member and thus cannot be accessed from the subclass `GameWithTimeLimit`.

If you want to hide the GameName from outside callers but use it in subclasses, you ought to use the `protected` access modifier. But since you already have a public setter on your `GameName` property, it would make sense to just add a public getter too:

```
    public string GameName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.game_name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.game_name = value;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it in your subclasses and other classes:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.ToString());
        return "Time Limit for " + this.GameName + " is " + this.time_limit + " minutes";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default protection level for items inside a class is private, so `game_name` is a private field and can't be accessed by `game.game_name`

Create a public property

```cs
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* you're getting the error here:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Console.WriteLine(base.ToString());
    return "Time Limit for " + base.game_name + " is " + this.time_limit + " minutes";
}
```

This is in the `GameWithTimeLimit` class, which inherits from the `Game` class.  Child classes can use fields on parent classes, *but* those fields need to be at least `protected` in access level.  The default when not specified is `private`, which is what you have:

```
string game_name;
```

If this field is intended to be used by inheriting classes, you can make it protected:

```
protected string game_name;
```

Ideally, if something is meant to be used outside of the class (even by child classes), it should be a property.  So instead I'd suggest something like this:

```
protected string GameName { get; set; }
```

There are further options you can explore, such as fields which are privately writable but publicly (or protectedly) readable, etc.

For any given member exposed by a class, be it a property/method/constructor/etc., it's important to ask yourself what protection level is needed.  The "just make everything public so you don't have these problems" approach leads to its own problems.  If something *should* be private, make it private.  If it *should* be protected, make it protected.  And so on.  The decision is based on the externally-visible interface you want that class to expose.

Then, if you encounter a situation where you run into this error, you examine whether the protection level was wrong (the class' exposed interface needs to change) or whether the sitation itself is mistaken (the class is correct, the logic you've written needs to change).  Either one can be equally likely.